# Recycle the activity, for different elements of the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

:)So, I have a fragment, with a listview.
When I click on any item in the listview, the identify with ListView1, it opens a new fragment that another listview the identify with ListView2.
For each element of ListView2, I have to load a different list.

But I do not know how to do, I can load only.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stanze, container, false);
    Log.i("STANZEEEEE", "SONO NELLA FRAGMENT STANZE");
    listViewStanze = (ListView)fragment.findViewById(R.id.listViewStanze);
    listaStanze = Singleton.getInstance().getListaAbitazioni().get(2).getListaCase().get(0).getDettaglio().getListaStanze();
    adapterStanze = new AdapterStanze(listaStanze);
    listViewStanze.setAdapter(adapterStanze);
    return fragment;
}
```

As you can tell, I'm going to just load the list: listaStanze, having position 0: `getListaCase (). get (0) .getDettaglio (). getListaStanze ();`

But I'm interested, go put on each Item of listview2, a listaStanze different.

```
getListaCase (). Get (1) .getDettaglio (). GetListaStanze ();
 getListaCase (). Get (2) .getDettaglio (). GetListaStanze ();
 getListaCase (). Get (3) .getDettaglio (). GetListaStanze ();
```

Etc.

I would like to do this, to recycle the same Fragment, not necessarily other fragment, for each element of listaView1.
So I do not waste resources, and it all works dynamically

Or am I forced to create more fragment, for each element of ListView1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

It is not necessary to work in a static way, but I have to do it dynamically.

I have to use the Singleton, to impelentare methods Get and Set, the object that interests me.

In this case the object: **case** (in Italian)

In order to call the method **setSelectedCasa** in ListView1,
But the fragment, where I ListView2, call the **getSelectedCasa**, like this:

**Fragment 1, with ListView1:**

```
listViewCase.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {    
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        
Singleton.getInstance().setSelectedCasa(listaCase.get(position));        
Intent intent0 = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityStanze.class);                
startActivity(intent0);
}});
```

**Fragment 2, with ListView2**

```
listViewStanze = (ListView)fragment.findViewById(R.id.listViewStanze);
listaStanze = Singleton.getInstance().getSelectedCasa().getDettaglio().getListaStanze();
adapterStanze = new AdapterStanze(listaStanze);
listViewStanze.setAdapter(adapterStanze);
```

In this way, I could riclare, always the same view, for each item of listview.
In the same view, different data will be loaded based on the elements, in this case lists, based on the location of the ListView1, when the user tap on.

I spoke of Fragment, while the code you see the creation of an Activity.
I Use the Activity as my frame (as for programming Java Desktop), while the fragment as Panel.

Then for each "view", which are my fragment, I will have a container (FRAME) which is my activity.

Comment: If anyone wants advice, I am available :)